# Why cvWaitKey(0) doesn't work?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opencv

I'm not sure why, but for a mysterious reason my c++ application doesn't wait anymore when it reaches cvWaitKey(0) it just passes this line, like this function doesn't do anything!
I also tried cvWaitKey(100000) it doesn't work either...

```
void main() {
   cvWaitKey(0);
   return;
}
```

My project is a little complex, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and It includes opencv ffmpeg pthread winsocks and some other libraries.

Can you guess why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you called `cvNamedWindow` yet? It will not work without `cvNamedWindow`.

Comment: Exactly! Why these two are related?

Comment: I think it because of [cvWaitKey](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html), it needs `highgui`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the issue myself a few times, but I can only speculate on what causes this. I can offer a work-around though:

```
while(1){
  int key=cvWaitKey(10);
  if(key==27) break;
}
```

This will block until ESC is pressed.